# Prevent content form moving

Tags: html, css, navigation

I need some help with my code. I created a drop-down navigation menu. But when I hover over the sub-menus it pushes the main content of my website down. I don't want that. I want to be able to look at the sub-menus without infecting any of my main content. If I hover the menu it is pushing the other parts of the menu down. I like that, but when I tried to use position absolute, it isn't moving the other parts of the menu down anymore.
(Sorry for my bad English)

A part of the html code:

```
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Trajecten</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="trajecten/Sport.htm">Sport</a></li>
        <li><a href="trajecten/Techniek.htm">Techniek</a></li>
        <li><a href="trajecten/Moderne_Media.htm">Moderne Menia</a></li>
        <li><a href="trajecten/Fast_Lane_English.htm">Fast Lane English</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">2017/18</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="2017,18/Examenreis_Berlijn.htm">Examenreis Berlijn</a></li>
        <li><a href="2017,18/Examenreis_Londen.htm">Examenreis Londen</a></li>
        <li><a href="2017,18/Examenreis_Parijs.htm">Examenreis Parijs</a></li>
        <li><a href="2017,18/Introductie.htm">Introductie</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">2016/17</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="2016,17/Diploma_uitreiking_Havo.htm">Diploma uitreiking Havo</a></li>
        <li><a href="2016,17/Diploma_uitreiking_Mavo.htm">Diploma uitreiking Mavo</a></li>
        <li><a href="2016,17/Introductie.htm">Introductie</a></li>
        <li><a href="2016,17/Open_Dag.htm">Open Dag</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<center>
<p id="content">2017/18</p>
<a href="2017,18/Examenreis_Berlijn.htm"> <img id="picture" src="images/2017,18/Berlijn.jpg"></a>
</center>
```

Css code:

```
#content{
    font-size: 25px;
    position:relative;
    top: 25px;
}
#picture{
    width: 285px;
    position:relative;
    top: 30px;
}
html, body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/* Navigatie */
.navigation {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    width: 230px;
}
.mainmenu, .submenu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;
}
.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}
.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
    max-height: 420px;
}
.submenu a {
    background-color: #999;
    text-align: center;
}
.submenu a:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}
.submenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
    body{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    }
    #content{
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #picture{
        width: 285px;
    }
    html, body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Navigatie */
    .navigation {
        width: 230px;
    }
    .mainmenu, .submenu {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .mainmenu a {
        display: block;
        background-color: #CCC;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #000;
    }
    .mainmenu a:hover {
        background-color: #C5C5C5;
    }
    .mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
        display: block;
        max-height: 420px;
    }
    .submenu a {
        background-color: #999;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .submenu a:hover {
        background-color: #666;
    }
    .submenu {
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
    }
    center{
      width:calc(100% - 230px);
      display:flex;
      flex-grow:1;
      text-align:center;
      flex-direction:column;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="mainmenu">
        <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Trajecten</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="trajecten/Sport.htm">Sport</a></li>
            <li><a href="trajecten/Techniek.htm">Techniek</a></li>
            <li><a href="trajecten/Moderne_Media.htm">Moderne Menia</a></li>
            <li><a href="trajecten/Fast_Lane_English.htm">Fast Lane English</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">2017/18</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="2017,18/Examenreis_Berlijn.htm">Examenreis Berlijn</a></li>
            <li><a href="2017,18/Examenreis_Londen.htm">Examenreis Londen</a></li>
            <li><a href="2017,18/Examenreis_Parijs.htm">Examenreis Parijs</a></li>
            <li><a href="2017,18/Introductie.htm">Introductie</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">2016/17</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="2016,17/Diploma_uitreiking_Havo.htm">Diploma uitreiking Havo</a></li>
            <li><a href="2016,17/Diploma_uitreiking_Mavo.htm">Diploma uitreiking Mavo</a></li>
            <li><a href="2016,17/Introductie.htm">Introductie</a></li>
            <li><a href="2016,17/Open_Dag.htm">Open Dag</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <center>
    <p id="content">2017/18</p>
    <a href="2017,18/Examenreis_Berlijn.htm"> <img id="picture" src="images/2017,18/Berlijn.jpg"></a>
    </center>
```

made a few changes,
now it's better centerd
you can make one of the menus open if you use js

Comment: Thanks! But if I look at the page, the main content isn't centered. Is that possible? I forget the add this to my main question, is it possible that when you load the page it automatically expands one of the submenu's, trajecten for example?

Comment: made a few changes, now it's better centerd you can make one of the menus open if you use js

Comment: you can see example for active sub-menu here [link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/L87os6gv/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
nav, center{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

center{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}
```

Note: `<center>` tag is obsolete in HTML5

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/am90qn2s/4/)**